# Android views settling

Tags: android, android-layout

can somebody help me to achieve with views this picture:
[image: picture 1]

the **purple** and **green** rectangles are linear layouts in relative layout. I need to make if **green** layout visibility is set to **GONE** then **purple** layout will be on the bottom of the screen. [image]

Can somebody help me to achieve this?

I did not manage to find related question for this issue because it is very hard to make right question query for this type of problem.

Comment: you can programatically set its height to 0px after visibility is set to GONE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` with `gravity` as `bottom` and `orientation = vertical`. Now when you set `visibility = gone` for lower layout, above one comes to bottom automatically.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fisrt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to use `Relativelayout` as outer most then, put my code inside your `RelativeLayout` and set alignParentBottom = true.